# Garbage Disposal Housing Touching Drain Pipe

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink, garbage-disposal, p-trap

I have just taken out an old insinkerator badger 5 and I'm replacing it with a evolution select from Home Depot.  First some pictures:

Overall situation:

[image]

A closer look at the drain:

[image]

From underneath:

[image]

So, the outlet for the garbage disposal is just an inch or so too close.  I think I can fix that quite easily by shortening the pipe from the 2nd sink and pivoting the P-trap connection away from the disposal.  This will let me put in the outlet pipe into the top of the P-trap.

The bigger issue is that the housing of the garbage disposal is *just barely* touching the drain pipe (after the P-trap).  This can be seen from pictures above.

I really don't feel confident enough to move my drain lower, though if that were the only option, at least its all exposed.  I was wondering if I could rotate the T to the drain towards my supply valve just a hair and maybe I could get enough clearance -- then figure out how to rotate stuff until it all fits together.  However, looking at the T -- I can see the purple cement, so my guess is that I can't simply "rotate" it.

What would you guys recommend?  The more invasive the solution gets, the more I'm likely just to call a plumber.

Edit:

So, I've learned some terms:

[image]

Basically, I'm wondering if I can rotate my sanitary T going to my loop vent or if I have to lower it or if I should just call a plumber.